# Combinatorial Optimization - Variation on Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations

Here is a real-world combinatorial optimization problem.

We are given a large set of value propositions for a certain product. The value propositions are of different types but each type is independent and adds equal benefit to the overall product. In building the product, we can include any non-negative integer number of "units" of each type. However, after adding the first unit of a certain type, the marginal benefit of additional units of that type continually decreases. In fact, the marginal benefit of a new unit is the inverse of the number of units of that type, after adding the new unit. Our product must have a least one unit of some type, and there is a small correction that we must make to the overall value because of this requirement.

Let `T[]` be an array representing the number of each type in a certain production run of the product. Then the overall value `V` is given by (pseudo code):

```
V = 1
For Each t in T
    V = V * (t + 1)
Next t
V = V - 1 // correction
```

On cost side, units of the same type have the same cost. But units of different types each have unique, irrational costs. The number of types is large, but we are given an array of type costs `C[]` that is sorted from smallest to largest. Let's further assume that the type quantity array `T[]` is also sorted by cost from smallest to largest. Then the overall cost `U` is simply the sum of each unit cost:

```
U = 0
For i = 0, i < NumOfValueTypes
    U = U + T[i] * C[i]
Next i
```

So far so good. So here is the problem: Given product `P` with value `V` and cost `U`, find the product `Q` with the cost `U'` and value `V'`, having the minimal `U'` such that `U' > U`, `V'/U' > V/U`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.do you mean: Given P with value V and cost U. The question is to find the product Q with minimal cost U', such that U'>U and V'/U' > V/U ?

Comment: You never use this sentenve : " However, after adding the first unit of a certain type, the marginal benefit of additional units of that type continually decreases. In fact, the marginal benefit of a new unit is the inverse of the number of units of that type, after adding the new unit. " does T[] actually represent the benefits of each type ?

Comment: Can you post a complete example and work through it? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Ricky, yes that's exactly correct, and I've edited the post to clarify it.

Comment: @Ricky, regarding your second comment, `T[]` is related to the benefits through the formula that Produces `V` in the first code block. You can think of `T[]` like a kind of feature set, but as features of the same type pile up, they don't produce the same benefit. And yes, `T[]` is a non-negative integer array.

Comment: @IVlad, the examples I have are all complex. I am working on writing up a simpler example.

Comment: I think you mean, such that `U' > U`, `V'/U' > V/U`  (you want more bang for your buck, not less.

Comment: Is removing units from P an option, or is only adding units permitted?

Comment: @Zac, thanks for catching the typo. And, yes, removing units of one type and adding units of another type is definitely permitted.

Comment: Well, I thought about it for a while, and thought I had a decent solution, but then ... nope.  I'm not sure you *can* find the nearest best option without walking through the full set of nearby combinations and ranking them in order.  There are probably ways to speed it up by discarding some groups at once, but an efficient approach is beyond me for now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've described is nonlinear integer programming problem because it contains a product of integer variables `t`. Its feasibility set is not closed because of strict inequalities which can be worked around by using non-strict inequalities and adding a small positive number (epsilon) to the right hand sides. Then the problem can be formulated in AMPL as follows:

```
set Types;
param Costs{Types};      # C
param GivenProductValue; # V
param GivenProductCost;  # U
param Epsilon;

var units{Types} integer >= 0; # T
var productCost = sum {t in Types} units[t] * Costs[t];

minimize cost: productCost;
s.t. greaterCost: productCost >= GivenProductCost + Epsilon;
s.t. greaterValuePerCost:
  prod {t in Types} (units[t] + 1) - 1 >=
    productCost * GivenProductValue / GivenProductCost + Epsilon;
```

This problem can be solved using a nonlinear integer programming solver such as [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne).

Comment: Thanks. I think you are on the right track. I will try your answer.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "non-string" inequalities in this case?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's a typo, I meant "non-strict". Fixed.

Comment: The epsilon construction is problematic because the array `T[]` can be very large and I can't know in advance if I may be missing a solution using any particular epsilon. I am wondering if there is any way to do this using an open feasibiity set. As it turns out, though value in C[] are irrational, values of `U` are discrete and can be projected on to the integers. What I am doing currently is iterating through these projected values of `U` and then using an algorithm to find the greatest corresponding `V`. This works for small numbers but runtime is exponential in `U`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: I don't know of any MP methods operating on open feasibility sets. However, since the left-hand side of the greaterValuePerCost is integer and (productCost * GivenProductValue / GivenProductCost) is not necessarily integer it is unlikely that the equality will be obtained even if you drop Epsilon. If they happen to be equal you can cut off the solutions as described in http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-best-solutions.html until the one that satisfies strict inequality is found.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think there  is an easy way to solve this. The best thing would be to write the system and solve it with a solver (Excel solver will do the trick, but you can use [Ampl](http://www.ampl.com/DOWNLOADS/details.html#WinStd) to solve this non-linear program.)

**The Program:**

```
Define: U;
        V;
        C=[c1,...cn];

Variables: T=[t1,t2,...tn];

Objective Function: SUM(ti.ci)

Constraints:

For all i: ti integer
SUM(ti.ci) > U 
(PROD(ti+1)-1).U > V.SUM(ti.ci)
```

It works well with Excel: you just replace `>U` by `>=U+d` where `d` is the significative number of the costs (i.e if `C=[1.1, 1.8, 3.0, 9.3] d =0.1`) since Excel doesn't allow strict inequalities in the solver.

I guess with a real solver like [Ampl](http://www.ampl.com/DOWNLOADS/details.html#WinStd) it will work perfectly.

Hope it helps,